# Ruby Net::SSH will not give result of executed command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, net-ssh

Here is my code

```
Net::SSH.start("XXX.upload.akamai.com", "sshacs", :keys=>["#{ENV['AKAMAI_SSH_KEY']}"]) do |mk|

channel = mk.open_channel do |ch|

ch.exec("rm filename.mp4") do |tk, success|

if success
    puts "++++++++++++ Deleted: #{success.class}"

else
    puts "------------ NOT deleted: #{success.class}"

end

end

end



end
```

`success` is always True eventhough the file I want to remove does not even exist!

What's going on??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Net::SSH docs for Channel#exec](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/ssh/v2/api/classes/Net/SSH/Connection/Channel.html#M000052)

> In this case, success means that the command is being executed, not that it has completed,...

I'm wondering if you're getting success because it is successfully sending a request, and Net::SSH doesn't care if that request is complete or not. It did it's job, so it's a success.

combine it with something like: [on data](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/ssh/v2/api/classes/Net/SSH/Connection/Channel.html#M000064)

```
channel.on_data do |ch, data|
  puts "what am i really getting back: #{data.inspect}" 
end
```

Comment: Well I guessed that. BUT how will I know if file is deleted or not? In fact, how will I know any command inside exec command successfully executed and has no error?

Comment: The same doc talks about a callback, iirc.  add that.

Comment: I can't see any difference between my code and the code at the document? I had already seen that doc.

Comment: Well, on_data is triggered only if channel has some stout data. So if on_data is NOT called, that seems to mean that there's no problem... Although this doesn't sound the best way to me, I couldn't find any better solution or method. Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose to delete file you should use rm command. Like that

```
   ch.exec("rm filename.mp4") do |tk, success|
```

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typo. I've already been using rm command inside exec.